# Get javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException Error when use invokeHTTP after adding certificate to the truststore

Tags: java, docker, ssl-certificate, apache-nifi

I am using the apache/nifi docker image version 1.21.0 and trying to use the invokeHTTP processor to interact with an API in my local network.

I added the API certificate and root issuer certificate to a trustkeystore.jks file (both are local certificates). Then, I added the StandardSSLContextService to the invokeHTTP processor with the trustkeystore.jks file properties. However, I received the SSLPeerUnverifiedException exception, which said that my API hostname had not been verified.

Could you please help me with this issue?

I also tried StandardRestrictedSSLContextService and got same result.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.